# Nautilus crashes when trying to open workgroup folder in windows network (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: networking, nautilus, 14.04

I'm taking the first steps in the OS Ubuntu. started in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and after messing the OS because of Draftsight I decided to make a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. (Draftsight works flawless...)

In the Ubuntu 12.04 I had a shared folder to my Asus O!Play mediaplayer - could enter in local network via mediaplayer and see the shared folders in my computer.
After this new installation of Ubuntu the Nautilus crashes when I try to open the "Workgroup" folder in Windows network. (Nautilus crashes SIGSEGV).
Also noticed in network, my computer doesn't appear.

Like I said, this was a fresh install of 14.04, with installation of all updates available online. Recently re-installed Nautilus.

What is missing here? Any help would be great!

NEWS - Attempts made yesterday (06/05/2014)

Ran the Ubuntu 14.04 install disk and made the system recovery with upgrades online. Rebooted the system and ran the update notifier; installed all the upgrades available.
After tried to accesss the network - workgroup folder; works without problem.

Made the first attempt to share a folder; installed Samba like the system asked, when the system asks to install libpam-smbpass can't give the order because the board is greyed. Installed this manually by Synaptic.
Sucessfully share a folder, try to view the shared folder in network - workgroup folder; when I try to open the folder the Nautilus crashes.

Verifying the Nautilus files, three files are outdated: libnautilus-extension1a; nautilus-share and nautilus-sendto. Updated these with Synaptic.

Rebooted the system and made the steps to access the shared folder, nothing happens and nautilus crash again.

Strange thing, in Network my computer doesn't appear, only "smb-server"

Am I the only one to have this problem?

Thanks!

NEWS AT DATE 03/01/2015

I SUCCESSFULLY RESOLVED MY ISSUE WITH SAMBA AND SHARED FOLDERS - THE ONLY THING MADE WAS CHANGING THE HOSTNAME OF THE COMPUTER!!!

AFTER THIS I WAS ABLE TO "SEE" THE COMPUTER IN WORKGROUP NETWORK...AND ABLE TO SHARE A FOLDER WITH MY MEDIAPLAYER.

THANKS A LOT MASTERS OF UBUNTU BY IGNORING MY BASIC HELP.